# Every refresh new jsessionid is created of vaadin application

Tags: javascript, eclipse, google-chrome, tomcat, vaadin

Every refresh new Jsessionid is created of vaadin application in google chrome thats why, i am facing problem but in case of mozilla use exiting jsessionid,thats why its goods for me i want to use google chrome like mozilla that means after refresh chrome should use exiting Jsession .pls help me

in case of chrome url like:-localhost:8080/app
in case of mozilla url like:-localhost:8080/app/

if we add the trailing slash end of url manually like mozilla in google chrome than it works fine.pls help what we should do to add the trailing slash end of url in case of chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Try to play with sessionCookiePathUsesTrailingSlash and context.xml, for example:

```
<Context path="/app/" sessionCookiePathUsesTrailingSlash="true" />
```